# TypeError 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pytmx

I was having problems with transparency using pytmx in a project i was working on but it is quite long and not written very well. So i tried to make a smaller version that just made the tiledmap(this post) but i'm getting this error.

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/advcomp/testing/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    playGame.gameLoop()
  File "E:/advcomp/testing/main.py", line 21, in gameLoop
    self.loadMap()
  File "E:/advcomp/testing/main.py", line 30, in loadMap
    self.map_img = self.map.makeSurface()
  File "E:\advcomp\testing\loading.py", line 19, in makeSurface
    tiledSurface = pygame.surface((self.mapWidth, self.mapWidth))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

main.py

```
import pygame
from settings import *
from loading import *

class game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((displayWidth, displayHeight))
        pygame.display.set_caption(title)
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.gameRunning = True

    def loop(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.gameRunning = False

    def gameLoop(self):
        self.clock.tick(fps)
        self.loop()
        self.loadMap()
        self.editScreen()

    def editScreen(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.map_img, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()

    def loadMap(self):
        self.map = tiledMap()
        self.map_img = self.map.makeSurface()

playGame = game()
while playGame.gameRunning == True:
    playGame.gameLoop()
```

loading.py

```
import pygame
import pytmx

pygame.init()

class tiledMap():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gameMap = pytmx.load_pygame("maps\_testingMap.tmx")
        self.mapWidth = self.gameMap.width * self.gameMap.tilewidth
        self.mapHeight = self.gameMap.height * self.gameMap.tilewidth

    def render(self, surface):
        for layer in self.gameMap.visible_layers:
            for x,y,gid in layer:
                tile = pytmx.get_tile_image_by_gid(gid)
                surface.blit(tile, (x * self.gameMap.tilewidth, y * self.gameMap.tileheight))

    def makeSurface(self):
        tiledSurface = pygame.surface((self.mapWidth, self.mapWidth))
        self.render(tiledSurface)
        return tiledSurface
```

Comment: Post the full error message, it's a simple error but we can't help if we don't know what line caused it.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message?

Comment: Okay, i've added the full error message

Comment: Check [`pygame.surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).

Comment: Capitalization matters.

Comment: This is an very great approach to solving a problem! You're creating a smaller program that to tries to recreate the issue you had, which makes it much easier and faster to debug! This is called [mcve] and is very important on stackoverflow. The only unfortunate thing you came across was that pygame has a module `pygame.surface` and a class `pygame.Surface`. Just remember that classes always should start with capital letters (with very few exceptions), like `MyClass` or `Game` so you easily can identify what is a class and what is a module/function/variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def makeSurface(self):
    tiledSurface = pygame.Surface((self.mapWidth, self.mapWidth))
    self.render(tiledSurface)
    return tiledSurface
```

Notice I changed the capitalization of the second line above.  pygame.Surface is the class you are looking for, pygame.surface is not a class.